# Member array losing contents on each loop iteration

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a method that's parsing a file for tokens, and storing them in a char* array... this appears to be working somewhat, but the values aren't being saved into the object. I can loop through, and every time I restart at the do/while, my debugger shows that my member array has reset back to `""` -- stranger still is that every time I go to assign a value to the array, it repopulates the prior entries with the current data.

Example output:

```
Parsing
1 2 8
Token 0: 1
Token 1: 2
Token 2: 8
2 3 3
Token 3: 2
Token 4: 3
Token 5: 3
```

My `tokens` member data in the debugger at this point:

```
tokens  char *[25]  0x603020    
    tokens[0]   char *  0x7fffffffdc70 "2"  
    tokens[1]   char *  0x7fffffffdc72 "3"  
    tokens[2]   char *  0x7fffffffdc74 "3"  
    tokens[3]   char *  0x7fffffffdc70 "2"  
    tokens[4]   char *  0x7fffffffdc72 "3"  
    tokens[5]   char *  0x7fffffffdc74 "3"
    ...
```

So it appears the data is correct, but only during the loop it's on. What am I messing up here?

***main.cpp***

```
#include "includes.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int
RoutingManager::ParseInputFile(char* filePath, const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE,
                                const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE, const char* const DELIMITER)
{

    cout << "Parsing\n";

    ifstream theFile;
    theFile.open(filePath);

    if(!theFile.good())
    {
        cout << "No good\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int tokenIndex = 0;

    do
        {
            char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
            theFile.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

            cout << buf << endl;

            this->tokens[tokenIndex] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER);
            if (this->tokens[tokenIndex])
            {
                tokenIndex++;

                for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; i++, tokenIndex++)
                {
                    this->tokens[tokenIndex] = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);
                    cout << "Token " << tokenIndex-1 << ": " << this->tokens[tokenIndex-1] << endl;
                    if (!tokens[i])
                        break;
                }

                tokenIndex--;
            }
        }while (!theFile.eof());

        return 0;

}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    RoutingManager *manager = new RoutingManager();
    manager->ParseInputFile("/home/caleb/Documents/dev/cs438/tote2/mp2/build/topo.txt", 10, 3, " ");

    return 0;
}
```

***.h***

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

class RoutingManager
{
public:
    int ParseInputFile(char* filePath, const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512,
                                const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20, const char* const DELIMITER = " ");

public:
    char* topoFilePath;
    char* msgFilePath;
    static const int MAX_TOKENS = 25;
    char* tokens[MAX_TOKENS];
};
```

**Edit:** I wonder if this could have anything to do with strtok() modifying the data I'm saving in my array?

Answer (score 3):

`strtok` gives you pointers into `buf` - it doesn't allocate any memory. Then you refill `buf` with new data, and all those pointers just point into some random spots in that new data, spots where old tokens just happened to be before, but aren't no more.

Do yourself a favor and change `tokens` to `vector<string>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which object you're trying to save to when you said '...the values aren't being saved into the object'.  But anyhow, your code can be simplified somewhat:

```
int tokenIndex = 0;
char* pch;

do
    {
        char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
        theFile.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

        cout << buf << endl;

        pch = strtok(buf, DELIMITER);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE && pch; i++)
        {
            this->tokens[tokenIndex] = pch;
            cout << "Token " << tokenIndex << ": " << this->tokens[tokenIndex] << endl;
            tokenIndex++;
            pch = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER);

        }

        tokenIndex = 0;

    } while (!theFile.eof());
```